# Should we use an instrument when the independent variable is exogenous?

Tags: regression, instrumental-variables

Suppose I'm trying to estimate $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + u_i$ with $E[u_i \mid X_i] = 0$. I don't need an instrument. However, what if I have $Z_i$ such that $\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,Z_i) > 0$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X_i, u_i) = 0$. Let's rule out the case that the correlation between $Z_i$ and $X_i$ is small (i.e. our instrument is not weak). Is there any benefit to running a TSLS regression?

I know that $X_i$ is the best instrument for itself, intuitively. However, I can't provide a mathematical justification for this. I tried to show that without using $Z_i$ as an instrument, I get a more efficient estimator. However, I couldn't prove it.

Comment: I think it will become much clearer if you draw a causal diagram. How are $X, Y,$ and $Z$ related causally?

Comment: You could try to show whether or not Z provides a redundant moment condition in a GMM framework (generalized method of moments).